# Updating status of a page remotely with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, auto-update, facebook-authentication

I have an online blog which is custom written, by myself, with PHP. The articles & other features publish themself on a predefined date, which means that I can have 2 months of future content already lined up & writen, meaning that the site is constantly updating itself without my assistance.

Now I want to be able to update the facebook page, asociated with the blog, automatically. Is it possible to do this? All I want is for a new status to be made every time a new article is published, without me having to do it manually.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Seems the hardest part of this will be the authentication, access tokens are all short lived to keep out the spammers and autobotters.

Comment: can you post the code you are you publishing to your page with?  Also are you trying to post as the page or yourself.

Comment: Thanks! In the end I created an RSS feed from my articles table, which I then used a 3rd party app to publish feed items to my wall.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set-up a cron job (Scheduled task) to make this possible. This can be viewed in  the administrative panel.

You need to assign a (cron) file that lets you check your articles publishing date and today's date.

Comment: I have my cron jobs setup already, the automatically updating part is already working, its just the publishing to facebook part that i cant figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [facebook's api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and what it could do with [facebook pages](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/). I have never tried exactly what you want to do, but from my experience it seems that is very likely. I know you can automatically request an [access_token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and use that to publish updates onto a pages wall.

I think the combination of these two articles is what you are looking for:
[How to update a facebook page status using the facebook api](http://highgroove.com/articles/2009/07/19/how-to-update-a-facebook-page-status-using-the-facebook-api.html)
X
[Update your Facebook status using PHP and Graph API](http://www.digimantra.com/tutorials/update-facebook-status-php-graph-api/)

Comment: Thanks! In the end I created an RSS feed from my articles table, which I then used a 3rd party app to publish feed items to my wall.